# Typescript map in angular with AOT

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-aot

I am using typescript map `(testMap: Map<string, Array<string>> = new Map<string, Array<string>>();)` in my angular application and everything works if I run it using 'ng serve'. But if  run it using 'ng serve --aot', maps are not working. I don't get any exception but the maps are null when I debug my code. I want to know if it's a known issue and if there is a workaround for this. Thank you for your help.

//myLibrary

```
export class MyModule {
   static forRoot(config: MyConfig ): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyModule,
      providers: [
          {provide: MY_CONFIG, useValue: config} 
      ]
    }
  }

}


export class MyConfig {
    myArray? :  string[];
    myMap?: Map<string, string[]>;

}
```

//user application

```
export const testMap: Map<string, string[]> = new Map<string, string[]>();
testMap.set("key1", ["value1", "value2"]);
testMap.set("key2", ["value3", "value4"]);


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
// some code
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MyModule.forRoot({
        myArray: ["1234"],
        myMap: testMap,
      }
    ),
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: I do use maps all over the place and they do work perfectly fine with aot. You have to describe your use case with more details and online reproduction if possible to get help.

Comment: @PavelAgarkov Please check

Comment: I wanted to clarify if you really meant that Maps become null or just empty?

Comment: @TomaszBłachut in my test they were actually `undefined`. So I can confirm that maps don't work with aot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use anything that is not statically analyzable inside @NgModule if you want to build it with --aot
So you cannot call functions neither inside @NgModule nor in `static forRoot` method.
In order to create a `Map` it is necessary to call some functions (e.g. ctor, set).
You can replace `Map` with ordinary arrays and it will work.
Later on Map can be constructed from an array like this:

```ts
//...
export class MyConfig {
    myArray? :  string[];
    myMap?: [string, string[]][];

}
//...
export const testMap = [['test1', ['test1', 'test2']]]
//...
// setting up imports
MyModule.forRoot({
    myArray: ["1234"],
    myMap: testMap,
  }
),
//...
// config usage in your library
@Injectable()
export SomeService {
  private readonly myMap: Map<string, string[]>;
  constructor(@Inject(MY_CONFIG) config: MyConfig) {
    // converting from array to map
    this.myMap = new Map(config.myMap);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get how can I replace map with arrays? Could you please  explain it with a code snippet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've provided various instances constructed in NgModule's file. You just need to assign them to variable and then use this variable in providers array. Like OP did with export const testMap. That said I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: @TomaszBłachut can you please give me some code snippet to explain how to do it?

Comment: @TomaszBłachut I've tested both ways (inline and with const) and they don't work - map gets `undefined` when injected. For providers you can use factories but not for imports.

Comment: On second thought what I described is identical to injection of `MyConfig` instance. Would it mean that global JS class instances can't be handled by AOT? I find it hard to believe...

Comment: @TomaszBłachut, yes, you can construct a new instance of a class but directly in providers - not in imports. OP's problem also can be solved this way, but it would require a documentation for users to know what they need to specify in providers when this way they can see params of `forRoot`

Comment: @PavelAgarkov saying imports you mean that I can construct instance in `MyModule`'s file and create parameterless `forRoot` but can't pass it to `forRoot` from import location, is that correct? Gonna play with it latter because yet again when I thought I understood Angular DI it turns out I know nothing...

Comment: @TomaszBłachut, yes, that's correct. With providers you have more options. You even can use factories with injections like this: `{provide: SOME, useFactory: loadSome, deps: [Router, TransferState]}`